# Pass the Parameter in run time in crystal report 2010

Tags: crystal-reports

This is my Stored Procedure.

```
USE [DataStock]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[getBillData]    Script Date: 09/19/2014 10:47:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getBillData]    

@date1 varchar(20),

@date2 varchar(20)



AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    SELECT DISTINCT      [Billlist].[billno] [Bill No.],    temp.[BillDate] [Date],    [Billlist].[user] [Customer Name],    [Billlist].[total] Total,    [paid] Paid,    [discount] Discount FROM temp  JOIN [Billlist] ON temp.[billno] = [Billlist].[billno] WHERE temp.[BillDate] BETWEEN @date1 and @date2

END
GO
```

and my crystal report code is,

```
Report.BillListReport rptBurndown = new Report.BillListReport();
            CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo crDbConnection = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo();
            crDbConnection.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            crDbConnection.DatabaseName = "DataStock";
            crDbConnection.ServerName = ChangeableFields.ServerName;
            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database crDatabase = rptBurndown.Database;
            CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo oCrTableLoginInfo;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table oCrTable in
              crDatabase.Tables)
            {
                oCrTableLoginInfo = oCrTable.LogOnInfo;
                oCrTableLoginInfo.ConnectionInfo = crDbConnection;
                oCrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(oCrTableLoginInfo);
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptBurndown;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I don't have idea to parse the parameter in Run Time.

In this code shown another pop up window comes when its running. I need to give that parameters in run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning to report source, call SetParameterValue with name and value for each parameter

```
rptBurndown.SetParameterValue("ParameterName", value);
```

Comment: Thank u @reckface! But it's doesn't works! That pop window comes again.

Comment: What window, what exactly is the pop up saying? Try calling SetLogonInfo, once and temporarily comment out the for each statement for applying logon info and see what happens.

Comment: There is not problem here! The pop up window ask to fill date1 and date2 fields!! and now the decimal part display like this ##### in another report what can i do?

Comment: Ensure the data you pass in the parameter value matches the expected data type. Can't comment on other report, but I can tell you that it is often unnecessary to apply logon info to each table. I have observed odd behaviour from doing that. I ended up calling SetLogonInfo once at the report level.

Comment: I have already apply loginfo na! Then why it's come? Some time it's running correctly. But mostly its ask Parameter values

Comment: Now its working well, That line has been giving end of the Report creating. Thank u so much!

Comment: Not before end of creating crystal report!